# Mapping Old to new URL is not working in Nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, 301-redirect

I am moving my old Url's to the new one (it is more than 50) so I have placed the URLs in a file but the redirection is not happening.

```
map_hash_max_size 262144;
map_hash_bucket_size 262144;

map $uri $new {
    include /etc/nginx/maps/redirect_example_com.map;
}


if ($new) {
         rewrite ^ $new redirect;
        }
```

and below URL is in the file redirect_example_com.map

```
/wp/articles  /aricles;
```

The same configuration is using in another virtual host which is working fine.

```
#map_hash_max_size 262144;
#map_hash_bucket_size 262144;


map $uri $new {
    include /etc/nginx/maps/redirect_hello_com.map;
}
 if ($new) {
         rewrite ^ $new redirect;
        }
```

Here I am not using the bucket size.

Comment: How are you using the `$new` variable in both configurations?

Comment: @RichardSmith Yes, I am using the `($new)` variable and edited the question.
 hello.com is working fine but example.com is not working.

Comment: what is `not working`? What is the error you experience? You have a typo in your .map file (`aricles` -> `articles`), if that's not a typo in this question only it will most probably an issue.

Comment: Are these two virtual hosts in the same instance of `nginx`? The `map` directive is in the `http` block and would need to use unique variable names, e.g. `$new1` and  `$new2`.

Comment: I have commented hash bucket size in hello.com. But if I comment the hash bucket size in example.com nginx is giving the error. `nginx: [emerg] could not build map_hash, you should increase map_hash_bucket_size: 64`,

Comment: @RichardSmith Yes, these two virtual hosts are running in the same instance only. Shall I put `$new2` instead of `$new` in example.com

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I have 50 Urls in the file which needs to be redirect from old to new but none of the url is not redirecting to the new once. I am not getting any error in nginx conf test and log. If I uncomment the hast bucket size then am getting the error. `nginx: [emerg] could not build map_hash, you should increase map_hash_bucket_size: 64`

Comment: @RichardSmith renamed the variable as `$new2` and now all the url's are redirecting fine. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 2):

The `map` directive is placed within the `http` block of an Nginx configuration. And although you may separate your configuration into separate files, Nginx interprets then as a single contiguous document.

So your configuration looks like this:

```
http {
    map $uri $new { ... }
    server {
        if ($new) { ... }
    }
    map $uri $new { ... }
    server {
        if ($new) { ... }
    }
}
```

You must rename one of your `$new` variables to something unique. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for more.